# PBS Pro: setting job array slot limit by the user

Tags: pbs

Using `torque`  user can specify slot limit when submitting the job array by using the `%`, e.g.: `qsub job.sh -t 1-20%5` will create a job array with 20 jobs, but with only 5 running simultaneously.

Currently I work with PBS Professional, but unfortunately, as far as I can see, option `%` is not supported. How can I achieve similar behavior as `%` in torque as simple as possible?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I had to write my script, which can handle this.